# Divert an entry into a list into another list if list gets to big

Tags: python, list

```
 list.append(elapse):
       if len(list) > 50:
          raise Exception(list_2.append(elapse))
       else:
          list.append(elapse)
```

I have no idea how to format this, I just want it so that once `list[]` gets to big the new entries are diverted into `list_2[]`, my original code doesn't have `raise Exception()` just `list_2.append(elapse)`. I'm only in highschool, week 6 of computer science so I don't know too much jargon.

Comment: Please don't name variables after class names. Use `lst`, not `list`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use an `if` / `else` construct as so:

```
if len(lst_1) >= 50:
    lst_2.append(elapse)
else:
    lst_1.append(elapse)
```

But think about your use case. Consider these questions:

- Why is your list size capped? Is this something that can be accounted for downstream?
- Will you have an indefinite number of lists? If so, consider using a dictionary of lists, or list of lists.

Answer (score 3):

simply make a 2 layer list:

```
mainList = [] # create the mainList to hold each list with 50 values in 
while True:
    innerList = [] # create the list to hold the 50 items
    for x in range(50): # run through your code 50 times to add 50 items to the list
        yourValue = 0 # your code to add to the list
        innerList.append(yourValue) # add the value
    mainList.append(innerList) # add the list of 50 values to the mainList
```

This means you can have an endless number of 50 item lists rather than limit yourself to a hard-coded number of lists :)

Comment: Just to show your same idea with `itertools`: https://bpaste.net/show/1554fd1d7553

Answer (score 1):

First off, you cannot name a `list` because `list` is a python built in name.

So call them `list1` and `list2` (Anything but `list`.

Of course you do not raise an exception like you did in python.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
if len(list1) > 50: # Check if list1 is full
    list_2.append(elapse) # append to list2 if list1 is full
else:
    list1.append(elapse)   #if list1 is not > 50, append to list1
```

if you wish you can use `elif` to check the len of list2.

You can have as many `elif` statements as you please but `else` is always last.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
if len(list1) > 50:
    list_2.append(elapse)
elif list2 > 50:
    print('OUT OF LISTS!!')
else:
    list1.append(elapse)
```

If you do wish to catch exceptions, ie if it is not a list you can wrap it in a `try` / `except` statemnent.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
try:
    if len(list1) > 50:
        list_2.append(elapse)
    elif list2 > 50:
        print('OUT OF LISTS!!')
    else:
        list1.append(elapse)
except TypeError:
    print('Not a List!!')
```

Some reading for you:

Error handling:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

`if /`elif`:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 1):

You an decide which list to append with for instance a *ternary operator*:

```
list_to_append = list1 if len(list1) < 50 else list2
list_to_append.append(elapse)
```

So first we check whether `len(list1) < 50`. If that is the case, we set `list_to_append = list1`, otherwise we set `list_to_append = list2`. We then append to that list.

Please do not name variables things like `list`, `set`, `dict`, etc. Since this will override the reference to the classes with the same name.